# How would I utilize ng-repeat instead of the Javascript loop for create the list of years in my drop down list?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I used Javascript to get the years 1960-2018 for my drop down list of years built for cars. When one year is chosen, it is pushed into the table through the "add" button along with make, model and number of doors. I was wondering how I could incorporate ng-repeat into the `<select id="dateYearBuilt">` instead of using just the Javascript loop? Thanks! Code is below.

```js
  

    var carsApp = angular.module('carsApp', []);
    
    carsApp.controller('carController', function ($scope) {
      $scope.cars = [];
      
      function hasDuplicates(newCar){
         var returnVal = false;
         angular.forEach($scope.cars, function(car, key){
            if (angular.equals(car, newCar))
            {
              returnVal = true;
            }
          });
         return returnVal;
      };


      $scope.add = function () {
          
          var newCar = {
            make: $scope.make,
            model: $scope.model,
            numDoors: $scope.numDoors,
            yearBuilt: $scope.yearBuilt
          };
     
          if (hasDuplicates(newCar)) {

              alert("Car already exists");

          } else {
           
              $scope.cars.push(newCar);
              $scope.make = null;
              $scope.model = null;
              $scope.numDoors = null;
              $scope.yearBuilt = null;
          }
          
      };      


      $scope.removeRow = function (deleteRow) {
         $scope.cars.splice(deleteRow, 1);
      };

      $scope.rowClick = function(car){
          $scope.make= car.make;
          $scope.model= car.model;
          $scope.numDoors= car.numDoors;
          $scope.yearBuilt= car.yearBuilt;
      };

      var max = new Date().getFullYear(),
        min = max - 57,
        max = max + 1,
        select = document.getElementById('dateYearBuilt');

      for (var i = min; i<=max; i++){
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = i;
        opt.innerHTML = i;
        select.appendChild(opt);
      };      
          
    });
```

```html
<html ng-app="carsApp">
<head>
  <title>Angular Test</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

  <style>


  </style>

<body ng-controller="carController">
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="make">Make</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="make" placeholder="Make" ng-model="make">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="numDoors">Number of Doors</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numDoors" placeholder="Number of Doors" ng-model="numDoors">
  </div>
</form>
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="model">Model</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="model" placeholder="Model" ng-model="model">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="yearBuilt">Year Built</label>
    <select id="dateYearBuilt" ng-model="yearBuilt">
      <option value="">Choose a Year</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <button ng-click="add()" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>

</form>
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>Make</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Number of Doors</th>
            <th>Year Built</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="car in cars" ng-click="rowClick(car)">
            <td>{{car.make}}</td>
            <td>{{car.model}}</td>
            <td>{{car.numDoors}}</td>
            <td>{{car.yearBuilt}}</td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Remove" class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-click="removeRow($index)"/></td>
        </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: You'll need a loop at some point unless you hard code the list of years.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html ng-app="carsApp">
<head>
  <title>Angular Test</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

  <style>


  </style>

<body ng-controller="carController">
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="make">Make</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="make" placeholder="Make" ng-model="make">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="numDoors">Number of Doors</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numDoors" placeholder="Number of Doors" ng-model="numDoors">
  </div>
</form>
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="model">Model</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="model" placeholder="Model" ng-model="model">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="yearBuilt">Year Built</label>
    <select ng-model="yearBuilt" ng-repeat="car in cars">
      <option value="">Choose a Year</option>
      <option value={{car.yearBuilt}}>{{car.yearBuilt}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <button ng-click="add()" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>

</form>
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>Make</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Number of Doors</th>
            <th>Year Built</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="car in cars" ng-click="rowClick(car)">
            <td>{{car.make}}</td>
            <td>{{car.model}}</td>
            <td>{{car.numDoors}}</td>
            <td>{{car.yearBuilt}}</td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Remove" class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-click="removeRow($index)"/></td>
        </tr>
  </table>
```

this is if you already had an array list of years called $scope.cars

for the other you can simply apply a datepicker

Comment: I just edited it again because I forgot to remove your ID call

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `ng-repeat` I would use [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) like so:

```
<select 
  ng-model="depositoryInitialValue" 
  ng-options="y.year for y in years">
</select>
```

Take a look at the code snippet below for reference.

```js
var app = angular.module('ngApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  'use strict';

  $scope.getyears = function() {
    var max = new Date().getFullYear(),
      min = max - 57,
      _max = max + 1;
    var input = [];
    for (var i = min; i <= _max; i += 1) {
      var year = {
        'year': i
      };
      input.push(year);

    }
    $scope.years = input;
    $scope.selectedYear = 'select year';

  };

  $scope.getyears();

}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ngApp">

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>maxisam's ngApp</title>
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
  <br/>

  <select 
      ng-model="depositoryInitialValue" 
      ng-options="y.year for y in years"
      >
  </select>
  
 <br />

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This worked well, but I am instructed to use ng-repeat. Thank you for the feedback though. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```js
var carsApp = angular.module('carsApp', []);
    
    carsApp.controller('carController', function ($scope) {
      $scope.cars = [];
      
      function hasDuplicates(newCar){
         var returnVal = false;
         angular.forEach($scope.cars, function(car, key){
            if (angular.equals(car, newCar))
            {
              returnVal = true;
            }
          });
         return returnVal;
      };


      $scope.add = function () {
          
          var newCar = {
            make: $scope.make,
            model: $scope.model,
            numDoors: $scope.numDoors,
            yearBuilt: $scope.yearBuilt
          };
     
          if (hasDuplicates(newCar)) {

              alert("Car already exists");

          } else {
           
              $scope.cars.push(newCar);
              $scope.make = null;
              $scope.model = null;
              $scope.numDoors = null;
              $scope.yearBuilt = null;
          }
          
      };      


      $scope.removeRow = function (deleteRow) {
         $scope.cars.splice(deleteRow, 1);
      };

      $scope.rowClick = function(car){
          $scope.make= car.make;
          $scope.model= car.model;
          $scope.numDoors= car.numDoors;
          $scope.yearBuilt= car.yearBuilt;
      };

      $scope.years = function() {
         var max = new Date().getFullYear(),
         min = max - 57,
         max = max + 1;
         var input = [];
         for (var i = min; i <= max; i += 1) {
             input.push(i);
         }
         return input;
     };
          
    });
```

```html
<html ng-app="carsApp">
<head>
  <title>Angular Test</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

  <style>


  </style>

<body ng-controller="carController">
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="make">Make</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="make" placeholder="Make" ng-model="make">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="numDoors">Number of Doors</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numDoors" placeholder="Number of Doors" ng-model="numDoors">
  </div>
</form>
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="model">Model</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="model" placeholder="Model" ng-model="model">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="yearBuilt">Year Built</label>
    <select id="dateYearBuilt">
      <option ng-repeat="n in years()" value="">{{n}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <button ng-click="add()" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>

</form>
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>Make</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Number of Doors</th>
            <th>Year Built</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="car in cars" ng-click="rowClick(car)">
            <td>{{car.make}}</td>
            <td>{{car.model}}</td>
            <td>{{car.numDoors}}</td>
            <td>{{car.yearBuilt}}</td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Remove" class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-click="removeRow($index)"/></td>
        </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Comment: @MurilloGoulart the Year Built still does not populate